# Speech(from wav Audio File which have PCM Audio data) to text Recognition API in IOS?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

am new to Voice Recognition .i can able to convert speech(recording from Device mic) to text Using by some  API like ispeech,openers,& so on .

But i couldn't find  any API for **Convert Audio wav file to text** . i think,can do with some external server (java) support via file sharing  . but i like to do without using internet .is there any API available for IOS ???

Comment: Sorry, I don't see openears implementing this right off but I'm sure if you look into how it is receiving audio inside of it's programming  you could come up with a way to send it a audio file instead.

Comment: thanks rezand for ur support.My Audio files from Call recording .so there is no way to do using openears concept .

Comment: If you are trying to record the IPhone's calls and then send them to speech the whole app isn't possible. They pretty much block access you would need or other issues like trying to record while mic is being used for the phone call.

Comment: Actually i have Voip module in My App . Which has internet calling support & have option to record during call . After Call gets over i have to convert recorded file into text for  their further reference.

Comment: ha ok as soon as you said what you were doing i also instantly thought of the google talk app i have for calls on my phone and with something like that it would be possible. Sounds like you have a great project on your hands, best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked into the sample of open ears demo and saw this so yes it is possible with open ears

```
- (void) startListening {

// startListeningWithLanguageModelAtPath:dictionaryAtPath:languageModelIsJSGF always needs to know the grammar file being used,
// the dictionary file being used, and whether the grammar is a JSGF. You must put in the correct value for languageModelIsJSGF.
// Inside of a single recognition loop, you can only use JSGF grammars or ARPA grammars, you can't switch between the two types.

// An ARPA grammar is the kind with a .languagemodel or .DMP file, and a JSGF grammar is the kind with a .gram file.

// If you wanted to just perform recognition on an isolated wav file for testing, you could do it as follows:

// NSString *wavPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"test.wav"];
//[self.pocketsphinxController runRecognitionOnWavFileAtPath:wavPath usingLanguageModelAtPath:self.pathToGrammarToStartAppWith dictionaryAtPath:self.pathToDictionaryToStartAppWith languageModelIsJSGF:FALSE];  // Starts the recognition loop.

// But under normal circumstances you'll probably want to do continuous recognition as follows:

[self.pocketsphinxController startListeningWithLanguageModelAtPath:self.pathToGrammarToStartAppWith dictionaryAtPath:self.pathToDictionaryToStartAppWith languageModelIsJSGF:FALSE];


}
```

Comment: thanks lot rezand .i too gone through PocketsphinxController & which asks dictionaryAtPath and some parameter so i thought that is related to some specific lang .now oly i have seen this line runRecognitionOnWavFileAtPath:wavPath   .once again will check and let u know.

Comment: problem is runRecognitionOnWavFileAtPath working for limited words(we have to specify LanguageModel & dictionary) . is it possible to point the Whole Eng Dictionary (like fliteController working) instead of words set ??   i can use some dumped Dictionary from http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/sphinx/models/#lm . but problem is it takes more processing time.

Comment: you asked was there any api for iOS  that could translate wav to text and I believe I answered that and you didn't check/accept the answer. It's obviously an answer because you say you have it working just now as well as you like.

Comment: Thank you for accepting answer, I looked at the file/link you showed me are you linking to this through the internet or storing it locally on the device? If locally stored on the device and pointed to then the process should be much faster.